# Accesing object stored in vector: use std::vector::at or std::vector::operator[]?

Tags: c++, vector

Is there really any difference between using `at` and brackets `[]` while accessing elements of vector?

I saw same people to prefer `myvector.at()` above `myvector[]`, is there something that makes it more preferable, like better performance in some situations, or being common with some other languages?

Answer (score 5):

The main difference is that `operator[]` is unchecked, and will result in Undefined Behaviour if you try access memory out of bounds of the vector, whereas `.at` does checks on the index and will throw [std::out_of_range](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/out_of_range) exception if you try access memory out of bounds

Comment: Unfortunately out of range access won't always segfault, you might also read uninitialized memory or another object's memory. More generally you get UB.

Comment: Edited, so it says UB instead of seg fault

Answer (score 4):

The difference between `std::vector::at` and `std::vector::operator[]` is that `at` will throw a `std::out_of_range` exception if the index is invalid, while `operator[]` will have undefined behaviour if the index is invalid.

The only reason that you would ever strongly prefer `at` is if your algorithm depends on an exception being thrown for out-of-bounds input. This seems like a very rare use-case, since it is straightforward to avoid out-of-bounds accesses through conscientious use of `size()` before any indexing operation, and so out-of-bounds accesses would usually simply be programming errors.

Assuming that an out-of-bound access is a bug rather than a valid execution path, the breakdown of `at` vs `operator[]` is as follows:

---

`at`:

#### advantages

- Guaranteed behaviour on all platforms
- Gives the ability (somewhat) to manage bugs at runtime

#### disadvantages

- Unclear whether out-of-bounds is a runtime error or a programming bug
- Unable to be optimised in release builds

`operator[]`:

#### advantages

- Gives more scope for bug management
  (for example, an implementation can provide an assert
   that captures all of the relevant context and breaks
   into a debugger or prints a debug message)
- Can be optimised in release builds
- Makes reasoning about code easier, as it makes it clear that an out-of-bounds access is a programming bug

#### disadvantages

- Behaviour not guaranteed on all platforms
- Can lead to security issues or other very major and hard-to-debug bugs, if an optimised implementation is chosen.

Overall, I would tend to almost always use `operator[]`, and choose either an optimised version or a debug version depending on my need. Converting bugs into runtime errors is rarely useful.

Answer (score 0):

`v.at(i)` checks if `i` is a valid index (ie, `0 <= i < v.size()`) and throws an exception if it is not. `v[i]` performs no such check and just tries to access the underlying buffer, and will (potentially) segfault* if `i` was not valid.

I would use `[]` if you know your index is valid.

* As Mankarse says accessing past the bounds of an array is undefined behavior. This specific instance of UB often results in segfaults, but could also just do other things you don't want/weren't expecting.